# Update Label Value after each interval of time

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

What I need to accomplish is to update a label after each 5 seconds. For that purpose, I am using UpdatePanel control. Following is the markup:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="NewsFeed_Item1_Name" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

On server side:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create a timer
    myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    // Tell the timer what top do when it elapses
    myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(UpdateNewsFeed);
    // Set it to go off every five seconds
    myTimer.Interval = 5000;
    // And start it        
    myTimer.Enabled = true;
}

private void UpdateNewsFeed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    //newsfeedCounter and dt are global variables
    if (newsfeedCounter >= dt.Rows.Count)
        newsfeedCounter = 0;
    string name = dt.Rows[newsfeedCounter]["Name"].ToString();
    NewsFeed_Item1_Name.Text = name;
    newsfeedCounter++;
}
```

But somehow the UpdateNewsFeed function is not triggered after each 5 seconds.

What is wrong with above code?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.Timers.Timer cannot talk to the webpage; to do this, you'll need to use an actual [Timer control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.timer%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which uses Javascript to refresh the page on the intervals you set.

There's a [walkthrough on the Timer control available here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386404%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working solution of your problem. you just need to add the following line of code in the `Page_Load()` method:

```
//add timer to the webform so we can get the ControlID
this.Form.Controls.Add(myTimer);

//An AJAX control to update the web UI
AsyncPostBackTrigger trigger = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();

//set timer to async it
trigger.ControlID = myTimer.UniqueID;
trigger.EventName = "Tick";     

//now add the timer trigger to get its updates   
UpdatePanel1.Triggers.Add(trigger);
```

Comment: Add a simple `Response.Write("something");` line in your `UpdateNewsFeed` method to check if timer is ticking or not

Comment: What do you mean by `redirecting` here? I was asking you to check whether the timer tick event is being raised or not?

Comment: oh sorry, I verified by adding Response.Redirect("Default.aspx") but redirect did not happen...

Comment: Kindly try what I asked you to do, and tell me the results

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38672/discussion-between-nida-sulheri-and-shaharyar)

Answer (score 0):

Just add this single line of code :

```
myTimer.Start();
```

after you enabled it.

**UPDATE**

Why don't you use `timer_tick()` event ? You have some sample [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.timer.tick.aspx), it could help you

Comment: Did that but nothing happened. Same issue!

Comment: `timer_tick()` event is not available in asp.net timers. It is for windows forms

Answer (score 0):

On a Web page you can't set the timer on server-side, it has to be done on client e.g.:

1. Set an invisible trigger control (for example a linkbutton with no Text set) inside of the Update Panel.
2. In server-side "OnClick" event of that control add your code to read the feed and update label
3. In *client-side* JavaScript use `window.setInterval` function to call linkbutton's `click()` method every 5 seconds.